# Making a dynamically generated file available for download

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download

My goal is to take some form inputs and prompt the user to download a summary of everything once a certain button is clicked. I have no need for the file once it is downloaded and so I'd like to have a solution where the data is streamed directly to the user. My current solution doesn't even prompt the user for a download. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I've got it wrapped as a webmethod and so I needed to add a definition of the _Default page class so I could access certain things.

```
Public Shared Sub SaveText(ByVal Text As String)
    Dim d As New _Default
    Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()

    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(d.Server.MapPath(FileName + ".txt"))
        sw.WriteLine(Text)
        sw.Close()
    End Using

    Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = Nothing


    fs = System.IO.File.Open(d.Server.MapPath(FileName + ".txt"), System.IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim btFile(fs.Length) As Byte
    fs.Read(btFile, 0, fs.Length)
    fs.Close()

    With HttpContext.Current.Response
        .AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=output.txt")
        .AddHeader("Content-Length", btFile.Length.ToString)
        .ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        .BinaryWrite(btFile)
        .End()
    End With
End Sub
```

Sorry this wasn't mentioned earlier but the webmethod is being called by an AJAX request!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing to the filesystem, use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) to hold the data from the database, or better yet, write directly to the [`Response.OutputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx).

The `Content-Disposition` header appears to be right, however, the correct mime-type (ContentType) for text files is `text/plain`.

Comment: Could the fact that I'm calling it via an ajax request (jquery) prevent the save dialog from appearing? I've stepped through everything and it seems to be working just fine..

Comment: @Radu - that's quite a detail that you omitted. The AJAX response will probably cause these headers to be ignored, so yeah, probable cause.

Comment: @Radu - The approach on the linked thread look promising (creating an IFrame to generate a new download). http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?8931-save-as-dialog-with-ajax&p=44739#post44739 and http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx#106904

Comment: Thank you! I'm probably going to work around the AJAX rather than work with IFrames and I'm going to try and use OutputStream as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a generic handler (*.ashx) file would fit perfectly here

Comment: Probably ideal but this is only used in a specific instance in this application.

Comment: I can't get your point. You always write a generic handler for a specific reason, e.g. showing thumbnails of pictures, getting images from a specific table from your database, et cetera. Why wouldn't a generic handler also fit for this situation?

Comment: I'm saying it's fit but not necessary since it's not being used more than once. Am I missing the point?

Comment: Yes, because other reasons I named for generic handlers also might have one placed they are used