# How to respond to a GET file request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want some external client to search in one specific directory of my ASP.NET website for a specific file, and that file should be generated (and given to the client) when the user makes a request.

Is it possible? Which method should I use to program this response?

Comment: what do you mean by petition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a dynamically generated file available for download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575118/making-a-dynamically-generated-file-available-for-download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could build an ASPX page for example that created the file on `Page_Load` and then set the `byte[]` of that file [to the `Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the page.

```
... Page_Load(...)
{
    // create the file

    // set the response
    Response.WriteFile(pathToNewFile);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work to me. That gives you the file when you enter the web, I want to generate the file when I enter "mydomain.com/file.txt", for example, where file.txt is a file in the root directory of mydomain.com's path.

Comment: @user3035445, then what you're looking for is an `HttpHandler`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090(v=vs.100).ASPX

Comment: Thanks, Michael, that is just what I was loking for. It worked perfectly :D

Comment: @xecollons, I'm glad I could be of assistance. Please consider up voting and marking it as the answer.